# What is meaning of ar[i].length in line 4 in given java code?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

```
class arrayClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] ar=new int[3][2];
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<ar[i].length;j++)
                ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It contains value of `i` which passed from first for loop and passed as index in `ar` array.

Answer (score 0):

there are missing code samples in you example, but I cansee that ar is a 2D table, so

```
ar[i].length
```

is the length of the 1D table in the line i or ar

Answer (score 0):

`ar[i].length` - find length of *i*-th subarray.